# How can i make this css star smaller?

Tags: css

I got the code below on :
https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

I would like to make the star smaller. I have try changing the height and width but nothing happens , how would I accomplish this?

I made this http://jsfiddle.net/YXe3k/

```
.star-five {
   margin: 50px 0;
   position: relative;
   display: block;
   color: red;
   width: 0px;
   height: 0px;
   border-right:  100px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 70px  solid red;
   border-left:   100px solid transparent;
   -moz-transform:    rotate(35deg);
   -webkit-transform: rotate(35deg);
   -ms-transform:     rotate(35deg);
   -o-transform:      rotate(35deg);
}
.star-five:before {
   border-bottom: 80px solid red;
   border-left: 30px solid transparent;
   border-right: 30px solid transparent;
   position: absolute;
   height: 10px;
   width: 0;
   top: -45px;
   left: -65px;
   display: block;
   content: '';
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-35deg);
   -moz-transform:    rotate(-35deg);
   -ms-transform:     rotate(-35deg);
   -o-transform:      rotate(-35deg);

}
.star-five:after {
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
   color: red;
   top: 3px;
   left: -105px;
   width: 0px;
   height: 0px;
   border-right: 100px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 70px solid red;
   border-left: 100px solid transparent;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-70deg);
   -moz-transform:    rotate(-70deg);
   -ms-transform:     rotate(-70deg);
   -o-transform:      rotate(-70deg);
   content: '';

}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use an icon font?

Comment: is there any real reason why this has to be CSS? SVG is now pretty widely supported, and it's much better for these kind of stuffs?

Comment: i never even heard of  SVG before, just research right now

Comment: @lie maybe im doing this the hard way cause all i want to show is 5 stars next to each other

Comment: SVG code is simpler, more maintainable, and SVG can be inlined within HTML. Example: http://www.w3schools.com/svg/tryit.asp?filename=trysvg_polygon3. If you want to tweak the star, there are many good, free SVG editors, like Inkscape. Using CSS like this is good only when you want to show off what's possible with CSS, not one that you should actually use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One easy way is to use the CSS scale transform in addition to your existing rotate transform:

```
-moz-transform:    rotate(35deg) scale(.5);
-webkit-transform: rotate(35deg) scale(.5);
-ms-transform:     rotate(35deg) scale(.5);
-o-transform:      rotate(35deg) scale(.5);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/YXe3k/3/)**

Comment: thanks, is there a way if i have more than one star i can have them next to each other? http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/YXe3k/3/

Answer (score 0):

That star is from CSS-Tricks but is not the best example to use. For have more control over size try using clip-path. Here is an example using clip-path inside a React Component with styled components.Just replace the width and height in order to increase or decrease star size.

```
import React, {Fragment} from 'react';
import styled from "@emotion/styled";

const StarClip = styled.div`
  background-color: #003BDE;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 61% 35%, 98% 35%, 68% 57%, 79% 91%, 50% 70%, 21% 91%, 32% 57%, 2% 35%, 39% 35%);
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
`

const Star = () => {
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <StarClip/>
        </Fragment>
    );
};

export default Star;
```